# Create XML File like my Example

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to Create an XML File. But now my problem is to create the following XML attribute:

```
<MsrProgram OwnerTypeFullName="myData" Number="0">
          <MsrRange2Width>4</MsrRange2Width>
</MsrProgram>
```

My problem are how to create the following attributes:
OwnerTypeFullName="myData"
Number="0"

Here is my XML Class:

```
public class MsrProgram
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the MsrRange2Width.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Value stored in ....
    /// </remarks>
    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "MsrRange2Width")]
    public string MsrRange2Width { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a Writing-Your-Code-For-You Service Center. Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement msrProgram = new XElement("MsrProgram", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("OwnerTypeFullName","myData"),
                new XAttribute("Number", 0),
                new XElement("MsrRange2Width",4)
            });


        }
    }
}
```